# How to set [Use Times Roman font, 12 pt font size, 10 pt line spacing, and 20 pica column width] in word for IEEE Communication Magazine?

Tags: ieee-style, ieeeconf

I am writing IEEE Communications Magazine Paper. What should be the typesetting in word for the following type: Use Times Roman font, 12 pt font size, 10 pt line spacing, and 20 pica column width.

I understand 12 pt font size in latex is different than the one in Microsoft word.

Comment: You can download a suitable template: https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/tools-for-ieee-authors/ieee-article-templates/ (click on the link “template selector”, direct link does not work)

Comment: My suggestion (BTW: welcome!) is 1) do what @crateane suggested and 2) do not worry about the format. Don't spend a single minute --- they gave you a template, use that, this is basically the good thing of LaTeX: write your paper and forget the details. They will do the final formatting anyway, so concentrate on the content!

Comment: @crateane Thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: @Rmano Thank you for the suggestion.